# How can I design a site like Stack Overflow with a constant menu at the top and only a body that refreshes?

Tags: php, html, ajax, layout

How would I go about designing a site with a similar layout to Stack Overflow (top menu bar that is always visible) and content body that reloads. I tried using ajax .load() to load in content to the main area but then I have issues with JavaScript not working. How does Stack Overflow accomplish this? I would like to do this in PHP.

Comment: What makes you think the bar at the top never reloads? If I gain reputation points, for example, and then navigate to a new page, the number displayed at the top is incremented.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's not what Stackoverflow does.

Comment: i fear its a little bit more complicated that that pal ;)

Comment: Well, let's forget the first part of the question.  SO seems to load each time, however, what are your JS problems you're having with ajax.load()?

Comment: One thing this question highlights: SO is so fast it appears to actually *not load parts of the page*. That's a pretty nice compliment right there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely a complicated question but I can address your issue with javascript not working, if I understand it correctly.

The problem (in simplified form) is of course that you don't have some elements (from, for example, "page2") when you first load the site (which is when JS loads), but when you use ajax.load() to load "page2" instead of "page1" the JS code doesn't reload and so whatever stuff you were doing with elements on "page2" doesn't work.

You do have to manually call the relevant functions when you load "page2". Now, if you just have events (like onclick, etc.) attached to various elements on "page2" then you could use live events in jQuery (if that's an option), which can be attached to non-existent objects and will become active when the object is created, in this case via ajax.load().

Answer (score 1):

This is something that some browsers (like Chrome) do whenever there is a constant stylesheet and layout. It appears to not reload some parts of the page because they don't change. They are, however, reloaded every time you click a link.

So to achieve this effect you should use a good layout with certain aspects that don't change on every click.